# How can I print the year from older value to current value?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use this code, but I don't understand what it is meant by,

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

/***********************************************
* Drop Down Date select script- by JavaScriptKit.com
* This notice MUST stay intact for use
* Visit JavaScript Kit at http://www.javascriptkit.com/ for this script and more
***********************************************/

var monthtext=['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sept','Oct','Nov','Dec'];
function populatedropdown(dayfield, monthfield, yearfield){
var today=new Date()
var dayfield=document.getElementById(dayfield)
var monthfield=document.getElementById(monthfield)
var yearfield=document.getElementById(yearfield)
for (var i=0; i<31; i++)
dayfield.options[i]=new Option(i, i+1)
***dayfield.options[today.getDate()]=new Option(today.getDate(), today.getDate(), true, true) //select today's day***
for (var m=0; m<12; m++)

 monthfield.options[m]=new Option(monthtext[m], monthtext[m])

monthfield.options[today.getMonth()]=new Option(monthtext[today.getMonth()], monthtext[today.getMonth()], true, true) //select today's month
var thisyear=today.getFullYear()
for (var y=0; y<20; y++){
yearfield.options[y]=new Option(thisyear, thisyear)
thisyear+=1
}
yearfield.options[0]=new Option(today.getFullYear(), today.getFullYear(), true, true) //select today's year
}
```

They have used this kind code for all three values, date, month and year. What are the values given for each parameter, and why?

I also want to print the year from an older year to the current year, I tried modifying it as follow, but I am getting the current year at the even when I open the drop down list. How can I remove that current year from the list?

```
var thisyear=today.getFullYear() //get the current year in four digit number
    var startyear=1990
    var x= thisyear - startyear
    for (var y=0; y<x-1; y++){ 
        //yearfield.options[y]=new Option(thisyear, thisyear)
        yearfield.options[y]=new Option(startyear, thisyear)
        startyear+=1
    }
```

Comment: Can you make a fiddle?

Comment: Ah...? How can i do that?

Comment: [Right here](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: i could make it print the year as i wanted with following corrections,
var thisyear=today.getFullYear() digit number
 var startyear=1990
 var x= thisyear - startyear
 for (var y=0; y<=x; y++){ 
  //yearfield.options[y]=new Option(thisyear, thisyear)
  yearfield.options[y]=new Option(startyear, thisyear)
  startyear+=1
 }
 yearfield.options[x]=new Option(today.getFullYear(), today.getFullYear(), true, true) 
 }

but still i would like if someone colud explain,

monthfield.options[today.getMonth()]=new Option(monthtext[today.getMonth()], monthtext[today.getMonth()], true, true)

Comment: If you can solve your problem what is the problem? A fiddle really helps to visualize and play with your code to see what is going on and how your HTML/Script/CSS interact

Comment: Can you please explain this statement, what these parameter are,

 monthfield.options[today.getMonth()]=new Option(monthtext[today.getMonth()], monthtext[today.getMonth()], true, true)

Answer (score 0):

change

```
var thisyear=today.getFullYear()
```

to

```
var thisyear=2005
```

(let say the year before is 2005). Then, change

```
yearfield.options[0]=new Option(today.getFullYear(), today.getFullYear(), true, true)
```

to

```
yearfield.options[today.getFullYear()-2005]=new Option(today.getFullYear(), today.getFullYear(), true, true)
```